# How to insert a table inside a contentControl using Word javascript api

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am developing a word add-in using word JavaScript api, I need to insert some data in table format inside the content Control and placed that content control on top of document.
Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be quite a simple operation. I am assuming that by "On top" of the document you mean inserting a table where the document starts. First line.

All the insertion methods have an insertionLocation parameter that you can use for that purpose. On this case you want to do a body.isnertTable, the 3rd parameter is the insertionLocation  ("start" is sent to insert at the beginning of the body of the document).

Once its inserted you can actually wrap it with a content control. Check sample below for details. I included other details, such as applying a built-in style to the inserted table.

hope this unblocks you. thx!

```js
function insertTableAndWrapWithCC() { 
     Word.run(function (context) {
          // We need a 2D array to hold the initial table values
          var data = [["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple"],["Tokyo","Beijing", "Seattle"]];
          var table = context.document.body.insertTable(3, 3, "start", data);
          table.styleBuiltIn = Word.Style.gridTable5Dark_Accent2;
//now we insert the content control on the table.
          var myContentControl = table.insertContentControl();
          myContentControl.title = "CC Title";
          return context.sync()
     })
     .catch(function (e) {
             console.log(e.message);
              })
     }
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response, it's working as expected. How the table content will edit, as i am loading the CC using Tag and want to replace the table content with new values. Please advice. Thanks.